# Validate radio button that depends on a value in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-models, django-forms

views.py

```
def method(request):
    settings = Setting.objects.get(user = user)
return render(request,'index.html',{'settings':settings})
```

models.py

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    date_format = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

index.html:

```
<script>
function(){
   var format1 = document.getElementById("id_date_format_1");
   var format2 = document.getElementById("id_date_format_2");
   if (settings.date_format == True)
   {
     $('format1' = checked)
     }else{
     $('format0' = checked)
 }
}
</script>
```

I want to validate the radio button. I am uisng django.

So if the value in date_format is 1, I need to show the radio button as checked otherwise unchecked.

I tried with the above code but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so; django template tag render "{{ settings.date_format }}" --> True or False ok ? date_format variable replace boolean javascript.

```
var format0 = document.getElementById("id_date_format_0");
var format1 = document.getElementById("id_date_format_1");


var date_format = "{{ settings.date_format }}" == "True" ? true : false; 

if (date_format) {
    format0.checked = true;
} else {
    format1.checked = true;
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/QsWdx/1/

Answer (score -1):

Use:- $('#format1').attr( "checked", "checked" ) to check the radio button

```
<script>
function(){
   var format1 = document.getElementById("id_date_format_1");
   var format2 = document.getElementById("id_date_format_2");
   if (settings.date_format == True)
   {
     $('#format1').attr( "checked", "checked" )
     }else{
     $('#format0').attr( "checked", "checked" )
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am sorry to say,it is not checking the radio button.In console i can see the line for value present in database for example it is showing the line  $('#format1').attr( "checked", "checked" ) if the value in database is true and else part is not visible.But in web page the particular radio  button is not in selected mode.